# How to adapt FullCalendar to display half-day event on month / year view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to reproduce with FullCalendar & React the "half day" functionality of year-calendar . The main goal is to display villa bookings on a calendar, so that the events take place over a full day, except for the first and last day of the booking. I need to "slice" the day diagonally to display departure and arrival events.

```
"use client"

import React from "react"
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react"
import multiMonthPlugin from "@fullcalendar/multimonth"
import { Booking } from "@/types/types"
import { formatBookingToEvent } from "@/lib/utils"
import { EventInput } from "@fullcalendar/core/index.js"

const MultiMonthCalendar = ({ bookings }: { bookings: Booking[] }) => {
    const events: EventInput = bookings?.map((booking: Booking) =>
        formatBookingToEvent(booking)
    )

    const checkInsConfirmed = bookings.map((booking) =>
        booking.bookingStatus === "Confirmed" ? booking.arrivalDate : null
    )
    const checkInsPending = bookings.map((booking) =>
        booking.bookingStatus === "Pending" ? booking.arrivalDate : null
    )
    const checkOutsConfirmed = bookings.map((booking) =>
        booking.bookingStatus === "Confirmed" ? booking.departureDate : null
    )
    const checkOutsPending = bookings.map((booking) =>
        booking.bookingStatus === "Pending" ? booking.departureDate : null
    )

    const isCheckInOrCheckOut = (date: string) => {
        let classNames: string[] = []
        if (checkInsConfirmed.includes(date))
            classNames.push("check-in-confirmed")
        if (checkInsPending.includes(date)) classNames.push("check-in-pending")
        if (checkOutsConfirmed.includes(date))
            classNames.push("check-out-confirmed")
        if (checkOutsPending.includes(date))
            classNames.push("check-out-pending")

        return classNames
    }

    return (
        <div className="text-sm mt-10">
            <FullCalendar
                plugins={[multiMonthPlugin]}
                initialView="multiMonthYear"
                height={850}
                eventDisplay="background"
                events={events}
                eventContent={(arg) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="flex h-full items-end">
                            <p className="text-xs">{arg.event.title}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                }}
                eventClick={(info) => {
                    console.log(info.event.id)
                }}
                dayCellClassNames={(arg) => {
                    const date = arg.date.toISOString().split("T")[0]
                    return isCheckInOrCheckOut(date)
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default MultiMonthCalendar
```

In this code, i'm checking if the date on the current cell is one of the events' start or end dates, and the status to add the right color. If it is, i'm adding the corresponding CSS classname to split the cell.

```
/* FC FULLCALENDAR */

.fc-bg-event {
    opacity: 50% !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.check-in-pending {
    background: linear-gradient(
            to left top,
            var(--pending) 50%,
            transparent 50%
        )
        no-repeat;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.check-out-pending {
    background: linear-gradient(
            to left top,
            transparent 50%,
            var(--pending) 50%
        )
        no-repeat;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.check-in-confirmed {
    background: linear-gradient(
            to left top,
            var(--confirmed) 50%,
            transparent 50%
        )
        no-repeat !important;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.check-out-confirmed {
    background: linear-gradient(
            to left top,
            transparent 50%,
            var(--confirmed) 50%
        )
        no-repeat;

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I'm stuck on the following points :

- I don't know how to remove / overright the Event' CSS on those specific cells, at the moment they are displaying the event color (full cell) and my half-cell color.

[image]

- When I have two events on the same day, even if my slices are 50% transparant, only one is displaying (supposed to have one green and one orange)

[image]

So far, I've tried to play with the dayCellClassNames props, that allow me to add CSS classnames conditionnaly, and with !important in CSS file on different classname.

The only solution i've found is to format the event with one day less on each side and apply the CSS. That is working but I still can't have both check in check out on the same day...